# Regex splitting on newline outside of quotes in VBA Macros

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I have a file which contains pipe separated string, I want to split that string on new lines that are **outside double quotes** using Split function of VBA if possible.
File date looks like this.
fileStr =  abc|hbd|hss
abd|"shs
hshs"|jdjd
hddn|hddd|sdjdd

desired ouput should be like below
Row 1 -> abc|hbd|hss
Row 2 -> abd|"shs
hshs"|jdjd
Row 3 -> hddn|hddd|sdjdd

I have tried Split(strData, vbNewLine)  but its not working.

Can you please give the code snippet which I can directly use in my VBA Code.

**Note: Need this in VBA Macros not in other languages**

Comment: Do you have multiple lines of text within quotes which you want to preserve ? If so split won't do that. How long is the string ?, maybe you could parse it one character at a time.

Comment: So you're saying you've got a pipe separated string you want to seperate on newlines.

Comment: When you give an example  in a question it's good practice to show the desired result, even when you think it's obvious. I assume you want the splitting to produce the strings `"Row 1 -> abc|hbd|hss"`, `"Row 2 -> abd|"shs\nhshs"|jdjd"` and `"Row 3 -> hddn|hddd|sdjdd"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you match, rather than split, using the following regular expression (with `re.Global = True`).

```
(?=.)[^"\r\n]*(?:"(?:[^"]*")+)?[^"\r\n]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hCoo7S/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
(?=.)      # positive lookahead asserts that a character follows
[^"\r\n]*  # match >= 0 characters other than double-quotes
           # and line terminators
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  "        # match a double-quote
  (?:      # begin a non-capture group
    [^"]*  # match >= 0 characters other than double-quotes
    "      # match a double-quote              
  )+       # end inner non-capture group and execute >= 1 times
)?         # end outer non-capture group and make it optional
[^"\r\n]*  # match >= 0 characters other than double-quotes
```

The purpose of the positive lookahead at the beginning is to avoid matching empty strings.

Comment: Nice Format and comments on that !

Comment: Note `[^"\r?\n]` is question mark part of class ?

Comment: @sln, thanks for the heads-up. Even worse, I see my comments were not vertically-aligned!

Comment: @CarySwoveland would be very helpful if you can give the VBA code snippet as well. Didn't really got your answer how I can use the above regex.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with VBA, but [this](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/#Matching_and_Displaying_a_Pattern_in_a_String) seems to be close to what you are looking for, just store rather than print the matches, with `regexOne.Pattern = "(?=.)[^"\r\n]*(?:"(?:[^"]*")+)?[^"\r\n]*"`. Please let me know if you get it to work.

Comment: @CarySwoveland    this works  regexOne.Pattern = "(?=.)[^""\n]*(?:""(?:[^""]*"")+)?[^""\n]*"  . Thank you so much for your help